# How to add nodes at dynamic positions in Cytoscape.js?

Tags: cytoscape.js

I am using Cytoscape to draw a group based diagram, I have choose 'preset' layout for this but I came to know that i need to define positions in this, as json is dynamic from database, how should i generate the positions and attached to every single node.

Please show me the correct path..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Define `node.position` for each node, if you want to use the preset layout (i.e. predefined positions).  Refer to the [JSON spec](http://js.cytoscape.org/#notation/elements-json).

Or, if you want automatic positioning, use one of the [included layouts](http://js.cytoscape.org/#layouts) or [layout extensions](http://js.cytoscape.org/#extensions/layout-extensions).